# CreateProcessW fails (ACESS_DENIED)

Tags: java, winapi, jna, createprocess

I currently convert an application to use `CreateProcessW()` instead of `Runtime.exec()` as I need the information it provides. However any call to CreateProcessW() fails with the error code 5 (ACCESS DENIED). I have been unable to find out why this happens as Runtime.exec() runs fine in the same case.

My error could be in one of the following code snippets, the method call and the jna interface.

```
public ProcessInfo createProcess(String dir, String name){
            ProcessInfo pi = new ProcessInfo();
            StartupInfo start = new StartupInfo();
            mem.CreateProcessW(new WString(name),
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    false,
                    0,
                    null,
                    new WString(dir),
                    start.getPointer(),
                    pi.getPointer());
            return pi;
        }
```

My definition of CreateProcessW

```
boolean CreateProcessW(WString apname,
                    char[] comline,
                    Pointer p,
                    Pointer p2,
                    boolean inheritHandles,
                    int createFlags,
                    String environment,
                    WString directory,
                    Pointer startinf,
                    Pointer processInfo);
```

Additional Info:

- Runtime.exec() succeeds with the given Strings
- The size of StartupInfo is set
- Testenvironment used: WinXP SP3 and Netbeans 6.9.1

Example parameters used:

- Name: moviemk.exe
- Dir: C:\Programme\Movie Maker\

Also tested with different paths, so not a whitespace problem

Thanks

**Update:**

As it turns out the error was caused by my calling code switching around working dir and exe path after I checked them. Because of the resulting access denied I actually thought that it at least found the exe. I will add an IllegalArgumentException to take care of that problem.

Since I had the additional error with the exe being relative to the working dir I will accept that answer. Thanks to all for helping.

Comment: Mixing `String` and `WString` is a red flag.  [`CreateProcessW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx) shouldn't be using any narrow character arguments, they should all be UCS-2 wide characters.  The single exception is `environment`, which is either ASCII or UCS-2 depending on whether `createFlags` includes `CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT`.  Why isn't `comline` declared as a `WString` like all the other UCS-2 arguments?

Comment: @Ben Voigt comline is documented as inout argument, so I thought that char[] would be better (with char[] -> jna -> wchar_t[]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CreateProcessW's first parameter has to be either a full path or a path relative to the current directory. It can't be a path relative to the working directory parameter, which seems like what you're expecting it to do.

Try passing `C:\Programme\Movie Maker\moviemk.exe` as the name parameter

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter `lpApplicationName` of the [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) function will be used as `NULL` typically and the second parameter `lpCommandLine` should contain the command line starting with the program name which you want to start.

Just fry to switch the first and the second parameters which you use currently by the `CreateProcessW` call.

Comment: @josefx: Could you insert the exact values of parameters which you use?

Comment: @josefx: I find very strange the definition of `CreateProcessW`. You use `comline` as `char[]` instead of `WString`. It seems me your main problem. If you will use the `apname` parameter you will be have many restrictions. You will have to use full path to the exe, are unable to start process with parameters, will be unable to start CMD files and so on...

Comment: from what I know WString and char[] differ only in that char[] can be modified by the native function and it works both ways now that I resolved my error. Thanks for pointing out the limitations of using apname.

Answer (score 0):

What is the full path you are entering? `Runtime.exec` might be quoting the argument internally, and you could be running into this situation:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179147

Maybe there is a prefix to the path that exists and is causing it to try to execute a folder or other file?

Try putting quotes around the entire path and see if that helps.